# Did Facebook "x people like this" for scalability reasons?

Tags: facebook

I noticed that recently Facebook recently changed the friends who liked this feature on the News Feed. Before, it would show all your friend's names such as `Friend A, Friend B, and Friend C like this.` Now, it just shows `3 people like this` and when you click on it the list is fetched via AJAX. Before, this only happens when a lot of people like something, but now it happens when at least 2 friends like something.

Out of curiosity, did Facebook do this to make the user experience more uniform or is it for scalability reasons?

Comment: You may need to recheck your observation, the Friend A display is your personalized experience while "3 people like this" is the aggregated count of people you do not know. I just checked and was able to see four friends' names plus and an aggregated count of those people I did not know.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook will show the names of up to 3 people that you're friends with, and the rest just show up as "X people like this." :D

Answer (score 2):

This has not much to do with scalability. It's just a basic rule of user interface design to not display too much information at once. Instead, facebook provides an overview with the option (via clicking) to display the details. This is a sensible solution, and it is employed by most mature web applications.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just a way to handle items that are liked by dozens to hundreds of people- showing a block that big without being asked would be annoying when you just want to skim the feed.